# How to delete or update the previously uploaded image in Actveadmin after uploading a new image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Basically in my form i am uploading a pic and has the option to delete the picture when a picture already exists. But i would like to delete the image from my disk after a new picture was uploaded. How to do that in `ActiveAdmin`

Admin model:

```
f.inputs do
     
      f.input :image, as: :file, hint: (f.object.image.attached?) ? image_tag(url_for(f.object.image)) : content_tag(:span, "JPG oder PNG")
      if f.object.image.present?
        f.input :remove_image, as: :boolean, required: false, label: "Remove"
      end
end

f.actions
```

Model:

```
  belongs_to :parent
  default_scope { order(:position) }
  has_one_attached :image, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_writer :remove_image
  validates :image, blob: { content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] }
  before_validation :image_delete

  def remove_image
    @remove_image || false
  end

  def image_delete
    self.image.purge if self.remove_image == '1'
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i am posting my answer in case it helps someone in future. It's pretty easy but a bit tricky. I had to adjust my model a bit.

Removed `before_validation`

Model:

```
      belongs_to :parent
      default_scope { order(:position) }
      has_one_attached :image, :dependent => :destroy
      attr_writer :remove_image
      validates :image, blob: { content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'] }

     def remove_image
      @remove_image || false
     end
```

In admin model inside `controller` the method `update` gets called on form submission. Simply deleting the initial image and saving the new one from `params`

```
def update

      v = Model.find( params[:id] )

      if params[:model][:image].present?
        v.image.purge
        v.image = params[:model][:image]
      end

      if params[:model][:remove_image].present? && params[:model][:remove_image] == '1'
          v.image.purge
      end

      if v.save
        redirect_to model_path(v)
      else
        render :edit
      end

    end
```

since i also delete image individually `remove_image` was used.
More source: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/01/29/uploading-files-active-admin/